# Standard deviation in one pass in C++

Tags: c++, c++14, statistics

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134871/standard-deviation-in-one-pass-in-c-follow-up).)

I have this template function for computing standard deviation in one pass over the data. The underlying math is [here](https://coderodde.wordpress.com/2016/04/12/computing-standard-deviation-in-one-pass/).

**coderodde_sd.h**:

```
#ifndef CODERODDE_SD_H
#define CODERODDE_SD_H

#include <cmath>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace net {

    namespace coderodde {

        namespace stat {

            template<class Iter>
            double sd(Iter begin, Iter end)
            {
                typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type 
                                                             difference_type;

                difference_type distance = std::distance(begin, end);

                if (distance < 2)
                {
                    std::stringstream ss;
                    ss << "The standard deviation cannot be computed for "
                          "less than two elements. The input sequence has "
                       << distance 
                       << " elements.";

                    throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
                }

                typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type 
                                                             value_type;

                double x = 0.0;
                double x_squared = 0.0;

                for (Iter it = begin; it != end; ++it) 
                {
                    x += *it;
                    x_squared += (*it) * (*it);
                }

                return std::sqrt((x_squared - (x * x) / distance) / 
                                 (distance - 1)
                                );
            }

        } /* net::coderodde::stat */

    } /* net::coderodde */

} /* net */

#endif  /* CODERODDE_SD_H */
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "coderodde_sd.h"

using net::coderodde::stat::sd;
using std::cout;
using std::list;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double bad_array[]{1.0};

    try 
    {
        sd(bad_array, bad_array);
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error& error)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: " << error.what() << "\n";
    }

    try 
    {
        sd(bad_array, bad_array + 1);
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error& error)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: " << error.what() << "\n";
    }

    std::list<int> my_list = { 1, 5, 2, 4, 3 };

    cout << "Standard deviation: " 
         << sd(my_list.begin(), my_list.end())
         << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I tried hard to write idiomatic C++; please tell me where I failed to reach that ideal + any other critique.

Comment: Use `auto` and you'll no longer need to care about `difference_type`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, you have two passes over the list - `std::distance` works in linear time unless it operates on random access iterators.

A naive way to fix this is to calculate the number of elements inside your `for` loop and check it afterwards. But this way you'll pessimize performance for random access iterators.

To avoid this pessimization you can examine the `iterator_tag` of you `Iter` at compile time and decide whether you're going to call `std::distance` or count your elements in a loop.

The simplest way to do this is in C++14 is by [tag dispatching](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags#Example). Here is an example:

```
template<typename RandomAccessIter>
double sd(RandomAccessIter begin, RandomAccessIter end, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    // calling std::distance
}

template<typename ForwardIter>
double sd(ForwardIter begin, ForwardIter end, std::forward_iterator_tag)
{
    // counting elements in a loop
}

template<typename Iter>
double sd(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    // dispatching
    return sd(begin, end, typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category());
}
```

This code will corretly handle bidirectional iterators as well since `std::bidirectional_iterator_tag` inherits from `std::forward_iterator_tag`. And code duplication can be avoided by incaplusating common logic in separate functions.

Viola! Now you have only one pass.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it

Answer (score 1):

I'd rename your template parameter name - instead of `Iter` use a name that indicates what type of iterator is expected. In this case `InputIterator` should be fine.

Assuming you're using at least C++11, it would be more idiomatic to use

```
using difference_type = std::iterator_traits<Iter>::difference_type;
using value_type = std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;
```

You may also consider using some more functional features

```
struct StdDev {
    double value = 0.0;
    double squared = 0.0;
};

template <class InputIterator>
StdDev adder(const StdDev& left, const InputIterator& right) {
    double rightVal = *right;
    double rightSquared = rightVal * rightVal;

    return StdDev{left.value + rightVal, left.squared + rightSquared };
}

...

auto val = std::accumulate(begin, end, StdDev(), adder<Iter>);

return std::sqrt((val.squared - (val.value * val.value) / distance) / (distance - 1));
```